# Wronskian Determinant of solutions of a linear homogeneous equation can be identically zero or not zero at all.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

The ODE I am working with is, $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$. Let $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ be its solutions. Then, $W(x)=W(y_1,y_2)(x)$.

While trying to prove the above, I assume that in an interval $I$ containing $x_0, x_1, x_2$, $W(x_1) =0$ and $W(x_2)=0$ and $W(x)\neq0$ for any $x_1<x<x_2$.

Then the function should be continuous at end points and differentiable there too. If that is possible, then I cannot see any further contradiction as to why such a $W(x)$ cannot exist.

(At least on the basis of the fact, that if $W(x)\neq0$, $W(x)=W(x_0)e^{\int^x_{x_0} p(t)dt}$ )

Now using the conditions at end points, we get

$$\lim_{x\to x_1} W(x_0)e^{\int^x_{x_0} p(t)dt}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to x_1} p(x)W(x_0)e^{\int^x_{x_0} p(t)dt}=0$$
Since $W'(x)=-p(x)W(x)$.

And similarly for $x_2$.

Now if first condition is proved, the second one follows because $p(x)$ is assumed to be continuous function on $I$. So $p(x_1)$ must exist. Also, due to the same fact, $p(x)$ must be bounded on the closed interval $x_1<x<x_2$.

For the second condition, $-|x-x_0||M|<\int^x_{x_0} p(t)dt<|x-x_0||M|$.
So $0<e^{-|x-x_0||M|}<e^{\int^x_{x_0} p(t)dt}<e^{|x-x_0||M|}$.

So the limit cannot be zero.

Does this proof seem correct?

Also, can anyone suggest a simpler proof?

Comment: What is your ODE?  Why does Abel's formula hold only for $x\ne0$?

Comment: @user539887, since, $W'(x)=-pW(x)$, you can only integrate when $W(x)\neq0$. (Assuming $W(x_0)\neq0$ because otherwise, it would become $0$ everywhere in the closed interval)

Comment: What does $W(x)\ne0$ have in common with $x\ne0$?

Comment: @user539887, sorry I didn't get you?

Comment: See your line 7 from the above.

Comment: @user539887, see the edit please.

Comment: So, it follows in a straightforward way that for any two solutions their Wronskian is either constantly equal to zero or nowhere zero (and boundary conditions have nothing to do here).

Comment: @user539887, what if $W(x)$ is $0$ in some sub-interval and non-zero in rest? (The argument I take up in *my* proof)

Comment: This is impossible, by [Abel's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity).